# Sankey Diagram in Plotly Dash

Tags: plotly, dropdown, plotly-dash, plotly-python, sankey-diagram

I want to create a Sankey diagram in plotly dash related to a time dropdown. I guess I'm not really understanding how to do so! The dropdown is done correctly, but the Sankey is kind of hard for me.
I have a dataframe with multiple columns which I want them to be the source (sum of their values), and multiple columns which I want them to be the target separated. As I said earlier, I'm not really understanding how to configure that.
Could anyone help me with that? Thank you...

Comment: Could you share some sample data and the code you have so far?

Comment: I managed to do a Sankey diagram, but now I have a problem in pandas! The dropdown is to select a year, so in pandas I want to group my columns values by year and do the sum of each column during that year. Doing that, I'll be able to choose a year in the dropdown and the data will be filtered for that year. How can I do so?

Comment: Glad to hear the Sankey worked out. This sounds like a different enough issue to ask a new SO question (with sample data and runnable code) :)

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask) and then try to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas group by and sum for each month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69349243/pandas-group-by-and-sum-for-each-month)