# Pandas group by and sum for each month

Tags: pandas, dataframe, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I'm doing a Plotly Dash application in which there's a dropdown to select a year. In pandas I want to group my columns values by year and do the sum of each column during that year. Doing that, I'll be able to choose a month in the dropdown and the data will be filtered for that month to update then a Sankey diagram. How can I do so?
Columns: ['Month'] ; ['Value1'] ; ['Value2'] ... ; ['Value20'] // I think I have to create a new Data Frame in which I group my columns by month and the values will be the Sum of each column during each year. ['Month'] = 1,2,3,4, // ['Value1'] = (sum for month 1),(sum for month 2),(sum for month 3)... Apologies if I'm not explaining this in a clear way!

Comment: Please add a sample of your DataFrame along with your expected output.

Comment: If you add some sample code that shows us what you have done so far, that will help clarify things

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask) and then try to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- you have not specified any data or data structures.  Have built a structure that will define *nodes*, valid *flows* and *actual flows by date*
- from this structure, have built **year** and **month** filter drop downs using https://plotly.com/python/dropdowns/.  Note these are independent filters,  it's how the static structure of **updatemenus** work
- in this solution, generally **data frame** column names and **Sankey** **link** property names are the same.  If this is not the case with your data structure solution could be amended to use **dict** instead of **list**

#### nodes

|  | 0 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | A0 |
| 1 | A1 |
| 2 | B0 |
| 3 | B1 |
| 4 | C0 |
| 5 | C1 |

#### valid flows `dfflow`

| source | target | source_name | target_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 | A0 | B0 |
| 1 | 2 | A1 | B0 |
| 0 | 3 | A0 | B1 |
| 1 | 3 | A1 | B1 |
| 2 | 4 | B0 | C0 |
| 3 | 4 | B1 | C0 |
| 2 | 5 | B0 | C1 |
| 3 | 5 | B1 | C1 |

#### sample flows by date `df`

| source | target | source_name | target_name | value | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 | A0 | B0 | 3.58321 | 2020-07-31 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 2 | A1 | B0 | 4.74713 | 2020-07-31 00:00:00 |
| 0 | 3 | A0 | B1 | 4.96593 | 2020-07-31 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 3 | A1 | B1 | 3.64883 | 2020-07-31 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 4 | B0 | C0 | 4.67168 | 2020-07-31 00:00:00 |
| 3 | 4 | B1 | C0 | 4.73339 | 2020-07-31 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 5 | B0 | C1 | 1.85678 | 2020-07-31 00:00:00 |
| 3 | 5 | B1 | C1 | 1.76691 | 2020-07-31 00:00:00 |
| 0 | 2 | A0 | B0 | 4.85048 | 2020-08-31 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 2 | A1 | B0 | 3.74573 | 2020-08-31 00:00:00 |
| 0 | 3 | A0 | B1 | 4.40529 | 2020-08-31 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 3 | A1 | B1 | 4.84975 | 2020-08-31 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 4 | B0 | C0 | 1.82983 | 2020-08-31 00:00:00 |
| 3 | 4 | B1 | C0 | 2.87512 | 2020-08-31 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 5 | B0 | C1 | 4.59346 | 2020-08-31 00:00:00 |

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import itertools

nodes = (
    pd.DataFrame(itertools.product(list("ABC"), range(2)))
    .astype(str)
    .apply("".join, axis=1)
)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    itertools.combinations(nodes.index, 2), columns=["source", "target"]
).pipe(lambda d: d.assign(value=np.random.randint(1, 5, len(d))))

# create dataframe of flows between nodes, A nodes to to B nodes, B nodes to C nodes
dfflow = pd.concat(
    [
        pd.DataFrame(
            itertools.product(
                nodes.loc[nodes.str[0] == l[0]].index.tolist(),
                nodes.loc[nodes.str[0] == l[1]].index.tolist(),
            ),
            columns=["source", "target"],
        )
        for l in ["AB", "BC"]
    ]
)

# for purpose of human readability, put node names on flows
dfflow = dfflow.merge(
    nodes.rename("source_name"), left_on="source", right_index=True
).merge(nodes.rename("target_name"), left_on="target", right_index=True)

# create some values against flows for a range of dates
df = pd.concat(
    [
        dfflow.assign(value=np.random.uniform(1, 5, len(dfflow)), date=d)
        for d in pd.date_range("1-jul-2020", freq="M", periods=14)
    ]
)

# utility function to build a dropdown menu
def menu(df, filter=pd.Series([0]), y=1):
    label = np.concatenate([filter.unique(), [-99]])
    return {
        "y":y,
        "buttons": [
            {
                "label": str(l) if not l==-99 else "All",
                "method": "restyle",
                "args": [
                    "link",
                    {
                        "label"
                        if attr == "date"
                        else attr: df.loc[filter == l , attr].values if l!=-99 else df.loc[:,attr].values
                        for attr in ["source", "target", "value", "date"]
                    },
                ],
            }
            for l in label
        ]
    }


# build the sankey diagram and the required filter drop downs
go.Figure(
    go.Sankey(
        node={"label": nodes.values},
        link={
            "source": df["source"],
            "target": df["target"],
            "value": df["value"],
            "label": df["date"],
        },
    )
).update_layout(
    margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 0, "b": 0},
    updatemenus=[
        menu(
            df,
            filter=df["date"].dt.year,
        ),
        menu(
            df,
            filter=df["date"].dt.month, y=.9
        ),
    ],
)
```

[image]